# Django admin panel lags and doesn't show anything

Tags: python, django

Today I've launched my Django project and saw a really weird behavior of Django admin panel. At the first sight, everything looks OK but as soon as I click on any model to view, I can't see anything. The most strange thing is that I've got no weird commits that could damage the contents of admin panel recently. The only commit could do that is updating Django to 3.1 version. I've already tried reinstalling Django and installing older versions but nothing works.

[Here is the typical admin panel homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fc2HO.png)

[Here is what happens when I click on models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1QIa.png)

I really need to know how to fix it as well as both me and my friend have this issue and we can't deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that you should check for this error is to see if you are calling:

```
admin.site.register(<model-name>)
```

and not

```
admin.register(<model-name>)
```

if this is not the case then try running the migrations again

```
python manage.py makemigrations 
python manage.py migrate
```

Finally, make sure your admin.py file with the code is actually inside the directory of the app (i.e. the same directory with your models.py that defines MyModel).

Comment: No, that's all fine. All migrations have been made as well as I use .register() properly.

Comment: Hm, I also have checked another Django project I was working on, the same issue there.

Comment: Can you see your INSTALLED APPS in settings.py and see where your app is defined. note that the app name should be defined right below the admin . if this isn't the case too then under Installed apps in settings.py change your 'Appname' to "YOUR_PROJECT.appname"

Comment: can you add your urls , admin and settings.py files to the question

Comment: @Guatamrk here is the repository: https://github.com/ideasoft-spb/school-diary